# How can I make react-bootstrap's Dropdown open on mouse hover?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, web

Ok the question is simple. I need to make the dropdown open when mouse hover rather than on click.

Currently my code is as follow.

```
    <Nav>
      <NavDropdown
        onMouseEnter = {()=> isOpen=true}
        open={isOpen}
        noCaret
        id="language-switcher-container"
      >
        <MenuItem>Only one Item</MenuItem>
      </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
```

as you can see, I tried onMouseEnter but no effect. Can someone solve this issue? What attribute should I pass in to achive this.

The API page is here [react-bootstrap API page](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#btn-dropdowns)

Comment: first if you need a component to re-render, you need to set a new state, or new props. you can achieve you goal by adding isOpen to state, and then call setState onMouseEnter

Comment: Yes, I adopted the exact same code as you suggest!! thanks for your help!

Answer (score 20):

```
export class Nav extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { isOpen: false }
  }

  handleOpen = () => {
    this.setState({ isOpen: true })
  }

  handleClose = () => {
     this.setState({ isOpen: false })
  }

  render() {
    return (
       <Nav>
        <NavDropdown
          onMouseEnter = { this.handleOpen }
          onMouseLeave = { this.handleClose }
          open={ this.state.isOpen }
          noCaret
          id="language-switcher-container"
        >
          <MenuItem>Only one Item</MenuItem>
        </NavDropdown>
      </Nav>
    )
  }
}
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: Thanks again, it works. I guess I need to change my mind from traditional frontend to state-controlled rendering technique.

Comment: The prop `open` does not exist anymore, it has been renamed to `show`

Comment: This technique will open all dropdown menus on the page. How do you limit this to targeted one, specific, dropdown? Or to hover over multiple other dropdowns throughout the page?

Comment: use the different state for different dropdowns

Answer (score 14):

A much cleaner pure CSS solution here:

`.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}`

Comment: It shouldn't be the accepted answer. Just try to move the mouse over the dropdown-menu element - the dropdown is closed again.

Comment: @rbtbar, are you using nested menus? I have tested without nesting menus and it works fine. "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.4"

Comment: This doesn't work in newer versions, the dropdown isn't rendered until it's first click. You'd need to trigger the onclick before you could control via css

Answer (score 3):

Having just run into this issue myself, I found out you need both the bootstrap CSS and a parameter for react-bootstrap. Add the following CSS:

```
.dropdown:hover>.dropdown-menu {
  display: block;
}
```

Then you need to add the parameter `renderMenuOnMount={true}` for the child elements to render on load:

```
<NavDropdown renderMenuOnMount={true}>
  <NavDropdown.Item href="#">Item #1</NavDropdown.Item>
</NavDropdown>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's as simple as that :)

```
<NavDropdown onMouseEnter={(e) => document.getElementById("idofthiselement").click()} onMouseLeave={(e) => document.getElementById("idofthiselement").click()} title="Others" id="idofthiselement">
```

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Rei Dien's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43012942/1438108), here's how you could do this using React Hooks.

```
export const Menu = () => {
  const [menuOpen, toggleMenuOpen] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Dropdown
      onMouseEnter={() => {
        toggleMenuOpen(true);
      }}
      onMouseLeave={() => {
        toggleMenuOpen(false);
      }}
      show={menuOpen}
    >
      <Dropdown.Toggle>
        Menu
      </Dropdown.Toggle>

      <Dropdown.Menu>
        <Dropdown.Item href="#">Menu!!!</Dropdown.Item>
      </Dropdown.Menu>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a hacky solution, but it was the easiest way to keep my app running after updating.

With the latest update the `dropdown-menu` isn't rendered until the button is clicked.

I've been using this in my css:

```
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-menu {
    display: block;
}
```

and added this to my component

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // TODO: Fix so menu renders automatically w/out click
    const hiddenNavToggle = document.getElementById('navbar__hamburger_wrapper-hidden_click')
    hiddenNavToggle.click()
    hiddenNavToggle.click()
  }
```

I added a wrapping div with the given id just to click for this.

I'd love to hear another solution.

Answer (score 0):

base on the answer of @Rei Dien

```
   onMouseEnter = { this.handleOpen.bind(this) }
   onMouseLeave = { this.handleClose.bind(this) }
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
const HoverDropDown = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
   const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

   return (
      <NavDropdown {...rest} show={show} onMouseEnter={() => setShow(true)} onMouseLeave={() => setShow(false)}>
         {children}
      </NavDropdown>
   );
}

<Nav>
   <HoverDropDown id="language-switcher-container" title="Menu">
      <Dropdown.Item>Item 1</Dropdown.Item>
   </HoverDropDown>         
</Nav>
```

Answer (score -2):

You could replicate this https://codepen.io/bsngr/pen/frDqh which uses the following JS

```
$('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeIn(500);
}, function() {
  $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(500);
});
```

Or alternatively you could install a plugin like this https://github.com/CWSpear/bootstrap-hover-dropdown

EDIT: Perfectly fine solutions to bootstrap but I noticed now you said its react and I havent used that before but I dont see why the js above wouldnt work even if it requires tweaking

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes I'm using bootstrap thus do it this way might not be a good idea,

Comment: Like I say im not familiar with react, but I am with bootstrap. If you pop that code in your own js file and make sure you have a .dropdown-menu etc so that it works, then i dont see why it wouldnt be a good idea?

Comment: Using jQuery to manipulate the DOM defeats the whole purpose of using React - a component library.